# prev() is not working it seems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have my code like this in one file...

```
      $d = new db();
class db
{
 function fetchform()
 {
    global $wpdb;
    $content='';
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("select * from kp_contact_form",ARRAY_A);
    $path =plugins_url().'/kp_contactus/ajax.php';
    $content.='<form action="'.$path.'" method="POST">';
    $content.= '<table><span id="error"></span>';
    foreach ($result as $row )
    {
        $content.='<tr><td><label>'.$row['label'].'</label> </td>
        <td><input type="'.$row['type'].'" name="'.$row['name'].'" required> </td>
        <td><a href="#" id="'.$row['fid'].'" class="remove">Remove</a></td>';
    }
    echo $content;
  }
}
```

**here i am printing above function data**

```
 <div id="showform" style="margin-top: -100px">
        <?php $d->fetchform(); ?>
 </div>
```

Now i am trying to get **name** attribute of **input type**

```
 $(".remove").click(function(){
        alert("hii");
        var fid=$(this).prev().attr('name');
        alert(fid); // giving undefined
  }
```

when i am doing **alert** i am getting **undefined**... i don't know what's going wrong with my code..

can anybody help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: We don't need PHP content, you should rather provide the resulting HTML (only the most interesting bits please).

Answer (score 2):

The previous element for `.remove` is... nothing! This is because `.remove` is the first element inside the `td`. You need to grab the parent element, its previous sibling, finally the input element within:

```
var fid = $(this).parent().prev().find("input").attr('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the `a` is inside a `td` and thus doesn't have a sibling. What you can do is:

```
$(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').attr('name');
```

This selects the closest `td` parent, selects the previous `td`, then the `input` inside that.

Clarification:
I chose `closest()` instead of `parent()` because if you happen to wrap the `a` inside another element later on `closest()` will still work.

Answer (score 0):

this is the remove link, it's the only child for the td, so no prev(), try this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('name')
```